# Is it possible to use a hook in another file in urlretrive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm creating a file downloader in Python using urlretrive.
I want to make a progress bar in the main file, but the function that is responsible for downloading is in another file.

main.py:

```
from download import dl

def bar(count, block_size, total_size):
    print(count)
    print(block_size)
    print(total_size)

dl("https://google.com/index.html")
```

download.py:

```
import urllib
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
from urllib.request import urlretrieve, urlopen


def dl(url,path=None):
    name = urlsplit(url).path.split("/")[-1]
    urlretrieve(url, name, reporthook = bar)
```

I want the *dl* function to use reporthook in the main file. Of course i get an error.

`NameError: name 'bar' is not defined`

Is there a way i can do that, or i have to put this function in the main file?

Comment: Pass in `bar` as an argument of `dl`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dl(url, bar, path=None):
    name = urlsplit(url).path.split("/")[-1]
    urlretrieve(url, name, reporthook = bar)
```

and

```
dl("https://google.com/index.html", bar)
```

worked.

#### Or

```
import download

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    download.dl("https://google.com/index.html")
```

and

```
...
import main

def dl(url, path=None):
    name = urlsplit(url).path.split("/")[-1]
    urlretrieve(url, name, reporthook = main.bar)
```

also worked.